# PHP: issue with converting to date format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I found the following function on the PHP Manual page that calculates the Orthodox Easter date (source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.easter-date.php).

```
function easterOrthodox_date($year) { 
    $a = $year % 4; 
    $b = $year % 7; 
    $c = $year % 19; 
    $d = (19 * $c + 15) % 30; 
    $e = (2 * $a + 4 * $b - $d + 34) % 7; 
    $month = floor(($d + $e + 114) / 31); 
    $day = (($d + $e + 114) % 31) + 1; 

    $de = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day + 13, $year); 

    return $de; 
}
```

I am using the following line to get this date for a certain year (`selYear`):

```
$EasterOrth = date('Y-m-d', easterOrthodox_date($selYear));
```

When I echo the result on my page this looks correct and shows 2014-04-20 (which is correct as for this year it is the same date as for the catholic Easter).

However, when I use this for other calculations it returns wrong results, e.g. the Dec 31. 
Is it possible that in this case I need to format this differently in order to get a date with the format yyyy-mm-dd ?

**Update:** 
The above variable is being passed to a stored procedure in SQL where I run the following Select (part of a longer query):

```
SELECT      DATEADD(d, daysFromEaster, @EasterOrth) AS dayX,
            category1,
            category2,
            '' AS validity
FROM        DayCheck_Easter
WHERE       mode = 'EasterOrth'
```

This should only fetch items from a table where the mode is set to EasterOrth and it seems the issue is with the first line here where I am adding a number of days (int). 
It works fine in several other Selects but here it calculates the wrong dates which is why I thought my formatting is wrong so that it isnt recognised as date.

Thanks, Mike.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're doing and what's not working? The last sentence seems to be the important bit, but it's unclear what you mean by it.

Comment: What exactly are the "other calculations"?

Comment: `date()` accepts any integer and formats it as specified. if you get wrong dates, then you're doing your date math wrong, and it's probably the a/b/c/d/e/month/day stuff, not mktime - that also accepts pretty much any integer and does its best

Comment: I'd start by taking the stored procedure out of the equation. Try various values and simply echo `$EasterOrth` to see if the results are what you expect.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in any of the PHP code that you're showing. It is either in other PHP code or it is in your stored procedure. The function that you posted appears to return the expect values for various years.  See this example: http://3v4l.org/nDEhr

Comment: Thanks, All ! It seems it is the stored procedure. I'll do some tests there and will then update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - it was neither the PHP nor the SQL but a typo in the Ajax that passes the variable which is why SQL couldn't read it properly.

Thanks again for all the help - it pointed me in the right direction.